# Make java setup for clients

Tags: java, exe, netbeans-7, setup-project, javaexe

I made software in java Netbeans. I have use small database that is in `ms access` database. 
          Now I want to make it for client. So, please help me for make setup that is embed with database.

If it is possible to make jar with database included then tell me how it can be done.

If it is possible to make exe that is included with database so please help me to make setup. One more thing I want to connect database for client without configure with `ODBC` connectivity. So Please help me for that.

Comment: don't use ms access. use a db that can run on any OS. If you want it embedded, use an embedded DB. do NOT make an exe. if you wanted an exe, you should never have programmed in Java.

Comment: which one is better for small db for client side

Answer (score 0):

use embedded-databases instead of ms-access :

- [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org)
- [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- [...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)